# Xcode closes immediately after loading .xcodeproj

Tags: xcode

Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 9B55 UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException):  Cannot update for observer  for the key path "_keyWindow.firstResponder" from , most likely because the value for the key "_keyWindow" has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent. Check the KVO-compliance of the IDEApplication class.

Above is the message in Xcode's problem report. Surprisingly, the .xcworkspace file works fine, but this isn't very helpful as I have integrated several API's in my project and hence can't run the xcworkspace. I haven't worked on this project in a few weeks but I don't remember running into this problem before. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting the  user data folder. Right click over the `.xcodeproj`/`.xcworkspace` and select `show package contents` > `xcuserdata`
and delete he `xcuserdatad` folder starting with your name after that quit and relaunch Xcode.

Comment: After 2 hours of searching, that's the answer that helped me!
Thanks!